# How do I add transition effects to each image coming from props onClick?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-props

I'm working on this code to make the image change on click, it works, but the transition between them is rough. Image and name both come from parent component `<App.js/>`, and I'd like to add an effect to them to make it more subtle. Images already have this kind of effect when they are visible on screen. This is the code for the `<Message.jsx/>` child component:

```
function Message(props){

    return (
        <div className="msg-div-index msg-div-height my-5">
            <h3 className="text-start fs-5 m-0 px-2">Make us</h3>
            <h2 className="msg-margin msg-lbl">{props.label}</h2>
            <img src={props.img} className={"img-fluid msg-img-index msg-img-opacity msg-img-border inline-photo" + (props.visible ? " is-visible" : "")} alt={props.imgAlt}></img>
        </div>
    )
    
}
export default Message
```

And this is the code for the `<App.js/>` parent component in case you need it:

```
function useOnScreen(options){
  const [ref, setRef] = useState(null);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      setVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
    }, options);

    if (ref) {
      observer.observe(ref);
    }

    return ( () => {
      if (ref) {
        observer.unobserve(ref);
      }
    })
  }, [ref, options]);
  console.log(visible);

  return [setRef, visible];
}

function App() {
  const [setRef, visible] = useOnScreen({ threshold: 0.2 });
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const imgArray = [{img: dance, label:"Dance", imgAlt:"People dancing"}, 
                    {img: cry, label:"Cry", imgAlt:"Sunset with guitars"}, 
                    {img: mariachi, label:"Remember", imgAlt:"Mariachi singing"}, 
                    {img: concert, label:"Sing along", imgAlt:"Concert"}];

  function handleClick(){
    if (index === imgArray.length - 1){
      setIndex(0)
    } else {
      setIndex(index + 1)
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App karaoke_bgr">
        <Header />
        <div ref={setRef} onClick={()=>handleClick()}>
            <Message visible={visible} img={imgArray[index].img} label={imgArray[index].label} imgAlt={imgArray[index].imgAlt}/>
          </div>
        <Options date="Friday, September 24th"/>
        <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I want to add a transition effect each time the props change (when the user clicks it), so the next image slowly appears. Thank you!
*Any suggestions about the code itself are highly appreciated. I'm new with React and trying to see what it can do.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-transition-group](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/switch-transition) for this

```
styles.css

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-exit-active {
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { SwitchTransition, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [setRef, visible] = useOnScreen({ threshold: 0.2 });
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const imgArray = [
    { img: "dance", label: "Dance", imgAlt: "People dancing" },
    { img: "cry", label: "Cry", imgAlt: "Sunset with guitars" },
    { img: "mariachi", label: "Remember", imgAlt: "Mariachi singing" },
    { img: "concert", label: "Sing along", imgAlt: "Concert" }
  ];

  function handleClick() {
    if (index === imgArray.length - 1) {
      setIndex(0);
    } else {
      setIndex(index + 1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App karaoke_bgr">
      <div ref={setRef} onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        <SwitchTransition>
          <CSSTransition
            key={index}
            addEndListener={(node, done) =>
              node.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false)
            }
            classNames="fade"
          >
            <Message
              visible={visible}
              img={imgArray[index].img}
              label={imgArray[index].label}
              imgAlt={imgArray[index].imgAlt}
            />
          </CSSTransition>
        </SwitchTransition>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```